# Use of undeclared type WKActionSheet

Tags: ios, webkit, wkwebview

I'm using `WebKit` with `WKWebView` and I'm trying to intercept the `WKActionSheet` that's presented after a long press on a link.

In my root view controller, I implemented `present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)`:

```
override func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {

    print("View controller to present: \(viewControllerToPresent)")

    super.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag, completion: completion)
}
```

When I long press on a link, I can see the related log in my console:

`View controller to present: <WKActionSheet: 0x13616b200>`

But if I try to check whether or the `viewControllerToPresent` is a `WKActionSheet`, then I got this error message:

`Use of undeclared type WKActionSheet`

So I guess... This `WKActionSheet` belongs to a private API ? There's no way to access that class ?

How could I determine if the `viewControllerToPresent` is a `WKActionSheet` in a clean way ? For now, I'm using `viewControllerToPresent.description` and I check if it contains the string "WKActionSheet"; it's ok but pretty dirty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested, here is my workaround for now.

```
override func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)
{
    guard let alertController = viewControllerToPresent as? UIAlertController,
        alertController.preferredStyle == .actionSheet, alertController.description.contains("WKActionSheet")
        else {
            super.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag, completion: completion)
            return
    }

    guard let longPressedLink = alertController.title
        else {return}

    // Here I call a custom method to create my own UIAlertController
    let customAlertController = getCustomAlertControllerFromLink(link: longPressedLink)
    super.present(customAlertController, animated: flag, completion: completion)
}
```